# error while running a GUI application in mini2440 board

Tags: arm, qt-creator, cross-compiling, qtembedded, linux-toolchain

i am trying to run a GUI application inside mini2440(FriendlyARM board that runs Qtopia).
I followed instructions from

http://mini2440vietnam.blogspot.com/2011/05/programming-application-for-mini2440-by.html

& the following from "tslib & Qt compilation" compilation

http://mini2440vietnam.blogspot.com/2011/04/upgrade-qt462-in-mini2440.html

i have set up necessary environment on my machine and also in Qt Creator as given in the blog.

i have followed all the instructions from this blog, but when i try to execute this application inside ubuntu bash terminal

(here i am connected to mini2440 using telnet
and the GUI application binary is in "/opt/Qtopia/bin")

i get the following error

```
[root@FriendlyARM bin]# ./HelloWorld 
QWSDisplay::Data::init: Invalid argument
Client can't attach to main ram memory.
Aborted
```

what is the problem here, was there any mistakes during my compilation.??

now that i understand that this is terminal and can't run GUI apps, but when i try to run this application inside mini2440 board, nothing happens, Qtopia/system doesn't even recognizes the binary and "?" sign appears as the application icon.

What is wrong with this?? and what will i have to do to  make this happen(run GUI application compiled from Qt Creator 2.0.1 in Linux) ???

thankyou.

Comment: we have to use the Qt GUI framework provided for FriendlyARM and should be downloaded from FriendlyARM's website.

Answer (score 0):

mabybe you need to export some environment variables (look at /etc/init.d/rcS or /bin/qtopia shell script). i can be wrong, but qt apps can be laucnched with -qws parameter, that specifies main display or main qtopia process